# Non-collapsing items twitter bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a best practice using twitter bootstrap when it comes to have a navbar with both items that are permanently fixed (even on mobile) and others that do collapse. When I try to add items outside of the collapse spacing gets removed on mobile devices. I could manually add a css rule, but I'm thinking there might be a way built in to handle this. Your advice would be greatly appreciated.

Mobile (with spacing issue):
[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My App</a>
            <div id="timer" class="navbar-text glyphicon glyphicon-time"><a href="#"></a></div>
            <div id="items-due" class="navbar-text glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></div>
            <div id="add-button" class="navbar-text glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></div>
            <div id="audio-button" class="navbar-text glyphicon glyphicon-volume-off"></div>
            <div id="info-button" class="navbar-text glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></div>
            <div id="back-button" class="navbar-text glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></div>
            <div id="next-button" class="navbar-text glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li id="forums-button"><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>
```

So to recap, what's the best way to have navbar items that don't collapse and are properly spaced on mobile displays?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have links with the icons you could put them inside a ul `navbar-nav list-inline` inside `navbar-header` like this..

```
      <div class="navbar-text">   
              <ul class="navbar-nav list-inline">
              <li>
                <a href="#"><span id="timer" class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></a>
              </li>
             ..
              <li>
                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></span></a>
              </li>
              </ul>
      </div>
```

http://bootply.com/99011

---

In general, to exclude menu items form the collapse, just keep them outside the `navbar-collapse`.

Comment: Wrapping them as links is ok, but when I load that up on a mobile device all of the glypicons line up vertically, rather than staying horizontal.

Comment: Aha! Adding list-inline does snap things into place nicely.

Comment: So is this solved? Help others by making this the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, but it never hurts to leave them open for a few extra hours to see if, by chance, a better answer comes along.

Comment: This adds the icons inside the header on the left side of the nav bar, but the rest of the links are on the right side. Is there a way to add non-collapsing links on the right?

Answer (score 0):

I created a less snippet that makes non-collapsing navbar items possible even on small screen sizes:

```
.navbar {
    // use this class instead of .collapse .navbar-collapse for the div surrounding the navbar items that should not collapse
    .no-collapse {
        @media (max-width: @grid-float-breakpoint-max) {
            .navbar-nav {
                margin-top: -@navbar-height;
                margin-bottom: 0;
                &.navbar-right {
                    float: right;
                    // summed up width and padding of .navbar-toggle elements
                    padding-right: 2*@navbar-padding-horizontal + 19px + 22px;
                }
                & .open {
                    .dropdown-menu {
                        .dropdown-menu();
                        display: block;
                        margin-top: 0;
                        .border-top-radius(0);
                    }
                }
            }
            li {
                display: inline-block;
                float: left;
                > a {
                    padding-top:    @navbar-padding-vertical;
                    padding-bottom: @navbar-padding-vertical;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will have to include the bootstrap less-files in your build environment though, to be able to use the mixins and variables.

Once you have that, you can add a `div class="no-collapse"` alongside with the collapsing div in the navbar:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="no-collapse">
                <!--...-->
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <!--...-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

inside that div you can add an ul-list with any li-elements as well as dropdowns, like you would with the regular collapsing navbar elements.

Comment: Doesn't appear to compile with Bootstrap 3.2 `@grid-float-breakpoint-max` is undefined.